# Grabbing some content from an iframe

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab the content of a div from within an iframe. I have the following code:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    content = $("iframe").contents().find("div#totaltime").html();
    alert(content);
  }, 800);
});
```

My alert message says "undefined" and yet when I remove the ".html()" I get an alert saying "[object Object]" ... any ideas how to extract the contents of this div. There should just be a time in the div like "1:33" but when I run .text() instead of .html() I just get a blank alert.

This is the html from inside the iframe:

```
<div id="totaltime" class="item graytext" style="visibility: visible; left: 368px; top: 51px; width: 32px; height: 16px; font-size: 11px; font-family: Arial;">06:44</div>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've changed to:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    content = $("iframe").html();
    alert(content);
  }, 800);
});
```

Now I just get a blank alert box.

Comment: Why do you wait for $('iframe') and then read from $("#iFrame") ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that in my code, but still same problem!

Comment: You grabbing iframe by tag name, there is only one iframe on a page? But wait $.load method is not for waiting for a iframe to load, but to load external stuff into this tag. See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `parent and child` *are* `both in the same domain` then, try this (`using pure javascript`). If they *are not* in the same domain, for security reasons, it is *not possible* access contents within an iframe of a different domain;

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("your_iframeId");
alert(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('totaltime').innerHTML);
```

Comment: I'm getting Chrome Extension: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL Domains, protocols and ports must match

Comment: Ah, to access anything like this both parent and child should be in the same domain